# Scala linked list

Tags: scala

Making my first steps in Scala, I have run into the first misunderstanding.
I took a classic example of a linked list.

```
sealed trait List[+A] // `List` data type, parameterized on a type, `A`
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] // A `List` data constructor representing the empty list
/* Another data constructor, representing nonempty lists. Note that `tail` is another `List[A]`,
which may be `Nil` or another `Cons`.
 */
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List { // `List` companion object. Contains functions for creating and working with lists.
  def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match { // A function that uses pattern matching to add up a list of integers
    case Nil => 0 // The sum of the empty list is 0.
    case Cons(x,xs) => x + sum(xs) // The sum of a list starting with `x` is `x` plus the sum of the rest of the list.
  }

  def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {
    case Nil => 1.0
    case Cons(0.0, _) => 0.0
    case Cons(x,xs) => x * product(xs)
  }

  def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = // Variadic function syntax
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

  val x = List(1,2,3,4,5) match {
    case Cons(x, Cons(2, Cons(4, _))) => x
    case Nil => 42
    case Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _)))) => x + y
    case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t)
    case _ => 101
  }
}
```

There are a few questions:
1) why custom linked List class doesn't conflict with built-in `scala.collection.immutable.List.type`

2) why a piece of code is supposed to be correct when we are matching built-in List to the custom linked list?

```
  val x = List(1,2,3,4,5) match {
    case Cons(x, Cons(2, Cons(4, _))) => x
    case Nil => 42
    case Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _)))) => x + y
    case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t)
    case _ => 101
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The custom linked-list class doesn't conflicts with the built-in `scala.collection.immutable.List.type` because local declarations, such as your custom List type, has higher precedence than an import (even non-explicit ones such as Scala's built-in `List`). See Chapter 2 of the [Scala Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for the full precedence order.
2. The referred matching code is not matching the built-in List, but your own locally declared List. You can see it yourself, by renaming your List to something like CustomList and see that some errors will appear, or to fully qualify the built-in List as the following code.

The following code actually matches the built-in List with your custom List structures and won't compile:

```
  val x = scala.collection.immutable.List(1,2,3,4,5) match {
    case Cons(x, Cons(2, Cons(4, _))) => x
    case Nil => 42
    case Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _)))) => x + y
    case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t)
    case _ => 101
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how is it possible to use a construction List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)? Does apply method give such opportunity?

Comment: You are calling the `apply[A](as: A*): List[A]` method of the `List` object.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really about *scope*, I believe. You have defined your own *List* which is unrelated to that in scala.collection.immutable... The same with Cons and Nil.

When you instantiate the List in part 2), you are instantiating your List, not the one in the Scala library.

Or am I missing something?